# Where is the review button?

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I signed up for the site and look up in the part were the review button was suppose to be it wasn't there as indicated by this screen shot here.

[image]

This seems kind of weird considering the fact that I signed up for a few private beta site before and there is all ways a review button as soon as I sign in. (because of automatically getting the close privilege.)

Please note the reviews are still accessible via the link: https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/review

<sub>If this is just a status by design feature and not a bug sorry for the misunderstanding.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Apparently you need [350 reputation](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) to access the review queue.